# Matlab Simulink S-Function: How to transfer the data from block to block except using a global variable

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

In my Simulink model, I have many Block S-Functions sharing a global variable. As we know, the value of the global variable will be transferred and possibly changed from block to block. I wonder if there is an alternative to transfer the data from block to block.

Comment: Can you please describe the problem a little more? Do you want to *unshare* the global variable, i.e have a copy of that variable per S-Function block? Or is it something else you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using pwork vectors to share c and c++ classes (or any other stuff) between functions. A pwork vector is actually just a pointer to an object.

Check this out:
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/sfg/elementary-work-vectors.html?searchHighlight=Pwork